# Can't get a passport. Can one get a NEXUS card instead?

Tags: passports, international-travel, us-citizens, nexus

I have a friend who is unable to get a passport because she was asked to provide extra documentation **which she cannot obtain, period**. The Department of State will not help.

They are asking for old documents and she does not have any history/records with any of them to satisfy them. **Note that she provided all accurate/requested information in first applying for a passport**, but the Department of State decided that wasn't enough -- **so they're asking for stuff she doesn't have and cannot obtain to give them because no such records exist that they want** -- namely, driver's license **5 years or older** (she has never had one), among 4 other documents 5 years or older that she has no records of and cannot provide. She's really frustrated and feels out of options.

[image]

I heard about NEXUS, and I was wondering if I should give that to her as an alternative? I read that you pay $50, submit to a background check, provide some info, and then have a short interview -- after that you get your card if you're approved. Can you get a NEXUS card with no passport though?

Could you use it, if so? She really has no other options to travel -- they won't give her a passport because she doesn't have old documents that they want and they will not compromise or help.

As a bonus question, is there any other way to get around this? Funny thing is that everybody she knows, including her family and friends, have applied for a passport exactly as her and were ALL approved without further ado, but she was unluckily asked for tough info.

To add, she's 19 years old and has next to nothing of what they're asking for -- except the social security card but it has no date so they probably won't accept it. Homeschooled so has no yearbook/student ID records of any sort and she has never had a job (one with an EI/ID).

Comment: @choster **Nothing** is incomplete. She went in person and provided all of the necessary info (valid ID, birth certificate, SSN/card, took a photo, filled the application and left nothing missing/incorrect, etc.). Everything was fine -- she submitted it to the official agency and they told her she should get a passport in about 4-6 weeks. 6 weeks later she got the letter I posted in the pic above. She has a valid government ID, social security card, birth certificate, and all of the above -- what they're asking for is what she doesn't have -- multiple documents 5 years or older as shown above.

Comment: @choster a 19 year old is not likely to have a 5-year-old state ID card, much less a driver's license.  Senejerry: where did she go to apply?  Was she born in the US?

Comment: @phoog I don't take that as literally asking for the address, but she did apply at an official application submission center, as noted by the official government website. **Yes, she was born in the U.S.**

Comment: @Senejerry I mean was it a "passport application acceptance facility" or a passport office?

Comment: @phoog An acceptance facility. But obviously it was submitted or else I don't see why the department is asking for more info if they didn't get any in the first place -- unless the acceptance facility made some mistake with the submission and didn't correctly note all of the provided info/etc.

Comment: @choster I don't quite get what you mean. I meant if she can apply for NEXUS separate from the passport process and use a NEXUS card without a passport.

Comment: @Senejerry Thanks; can you integrate the additional background into the question? If the State Department won't accept a new state ID, why would they accept a new NEXUS card? A NEXUS card doesn't replace a passport.

Comment: @choster A NEXUS card is an equivalent or alternative -- a valid travel document, according to the website.

Comment: @Senejerry NEXUS is a trusted traveler program. A card would be accepted for identification for re-entry to the United States from abroad, but would only really useful for visiting [WHTI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_Hemisphere_Travel_Initiative) countries, and you didn't indicate where she was planning to travel. I'm just trying to get a fuller picture of what's happening, and I'm not accusing her or you of making any mistakes. We've all been lost in the machinery of the government at some point or another.

Comment: @choster True, I get it -- but it's rather unfair how some people are asked for things they may not have, while others are simply granted without question. She wants to go to Canada so it shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: @Senejerry I would try to figure out what fault they found with the documents she submitted.  I assume that's already been tried, however, since you wrote that the Dep't of State won't help.

Comment: @Senejerry possibly related? Your friend wasn't delivered by a midwife in Texas by any chance, was she?  https://travelersunited.org/columns/still-no-passport-if-you-were-delivered-by-a-midwife-in-texas/  Or was her state ID a learner's permit?  http://inthesegenes.blogspot.com/2008/09/traveling-through.html Or was it out of state ID?  (see item 4 at https://travel.state.gov/content/passports/en/passports/first-time.html)

Comment: @phoog Nope ... she was delivered by a bookkeeper. Her ID was a same-state government ID; it wasn't out of state. I guess it's possible to call the Department again and word the questions differently.

Comment: It could be a name mix-up with someone on a watch list. Ask for a TSA redress number. Pull credit reports to make sure identity hasn't been hacked. Check SSA record as well. Contact local representative/senator's office and ask for their help.

Comment: Well a bookkeeper is probably worse even than a midwife; it's even farther removed from the usual doctor/hospital setup.  That is perhaps why they didn't like her documents.

Comment: This letter is almost always sent when there's a problem with the birth certificate. You should begin looking in that direction.

Comment: @MichaelHampton How do you figure?

Comment: Experience. You can take the advice or not, but applying for a NEXUS card is much more intrusive, and if you can't get a passport because of these document issues, you won't be getting a NEXUS card either.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I meant more so as, "How do I look in that direction?" as opposed to questioning your suggestion. I wasn't implying you were out of line or anything.

Comment: Without knowing exactly what documents were submitted, I could not begin to say.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I made it clear in the question that she submitted a valid, original birth certificate; a new, valid government ID; and provided a social security card -- that's all that is needed and the passport should be approved by, and generally is for most.

Comment: You didn't say anything about the birth certificate in the question! And simply saying it's "valid" and "original" doesn't really say anything about it either. Why do you believe it's "valid" and "original"? Where did it come from? Who issued it?

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to get a NEXUS card without a passport.  A US citizen must show *one* of the following documents:

> - a valid passport;
> - a birth certificate and photo ID;
> - a proof of U.S. citizenship;
> - a certificate of naturalization; or
> - a border crossing card.

Source: http://www.cbsa-asfc.gc.ca/publications/pub/bsf5084-eng.html

Unfortunately, the NEXUS card will be useless for travel outside North America.  Having it might help with future passport applications, however.

The question of how to satisfy the documentation requirements for the passport application itself is interesting, but should probably be asked as a separate question.

Comment: It wouldn't be useless for her since she wants to go to Canada. I also don't know if you are correct about air travel -- I've read that NEXUS is valid for air, sea and land.

Comment: @Senejerry apparently that is true.

Comment: I have a hard time believing it, but they say it's true -- however, whether or not they'll easily let you board a plane to Canada with only a NEXUS card and no passport, if possible, is up for questioning.

Comment: I also agree with you on splitting this up into two questions, but that doesn't sound like such an easy task.

Comment: @Senejerry well according to TIMATIC, the database the airlines use to decide whether to board people, one of several valid exemptions from the passport requirement for travel to Canada is "Nationals of USA with a NEXUS Card if residing in Canada or USA embarking in USA or Canada and entering Canada from the USA only."

Comment: @Senejerry you could use the image and ask a question about overcoming the document issue, and then you could edit this question to link to that question, saying "if someone can't get a passport because of [brief description of the problem], can they get a NEXUS card to enable travel to Canada?"

Comment: So then a NEXUS card is her only other option for now. Thanks. I don't quite get what you're proposing about the question bit though.

Comment: Just ask the questions separately and link them to each other with hyperlinks.  The question about the documents being refused is interesting and might elicit some helpful answers, but if it stays in this NEXUS card question as a "bonus question," people might miss it.  Also did you look into the affidavit option? They might accept that.

Comment: I wonder if NEXUS will be as skeptical of the photo ID as the State Department.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus as Michael Hampton pointed out in a comment (on the question itself), it seems to me that it's far more likely to be the birth certificate with which they've taken issue, not the photo ID.  But in fact I believe that NEXUS vets applicants both with the State Dept and their Canadian counterparts, so it's very likely to be true that "if you can't get a passport because of these document issues, you won't be getting a NEXUS card either."

Answer (score 3):

Touching on the passport issue, applying for a passport really only requires two documents, ID to prove you are you and a birth certificate or naturalization certificate to prove you are a US citizen.  The fact that the clerk who accepted her application assumed it was complete really means nothing, other than the clerk got the necessary documents from her. The clerk really doesn't have the ability or authority to double check the validity of those documents, that lies in the hands of the passport office itself.

As the Passport Office is requesting additional documents, means that one or both of her proofs are suspect.

Was the birth certificate an "original" or a certified copy from the government agency that records births where she was born?  If an "original", then consider getting a new certified copy of her birth certificate from the town/state she was born in.

Have you checked into the possibility of providing an Affidavit of Identifying Witness (DS-71 form) in lieu of the requested documents.

Does she have a bank account (that would have name & signature)?  Has she no school records?  No extracurricular activities at those schools (permission slips might have names, signatures, group photos)?

Comment: OP says she was home-schooled, so no yearbooks, usual school records, etc.

Comment: Why would an original birth certificate and brand new ID be suspect? If those two things raise alarms, I can't imagine why they wouldn't send this letter in the mail to 90% of the people applying then and make everyone go through this hell. Her friend is also a teenager like her -- actually, _younger_ -- and he was given a passport without further documentation despite having no credit, bank, driver's license, etc.

Comment: Also the document doesn't give bank accounts as an option for proof, and even if so she doesn't have a bank account signed from *five or more years ago*.

Comment: @Senejerry - in the last line of instructions it says you may submit any documents with name & photo or name & signature.  And since she has very few documents to use, I would submt anything you have even if it isn't on the list.  You don't get penalized for supplying extra info.

Comment: @Senejerry - ps: I doubt they send that letter to 90% of people applying, maybe to 90% of people who needed secondary screening.

Answer (score 1):

First, Tom has a good idea for a DS-71. Let me amplify the suggestion.

Assuming that the birth certificate is a proper certified copy, the issue is connecting your friend to the certificate. To this end, it may help to have documents like the government requests for her parents (to prove they are US Citizens or Permanent Residents), and DS-71 affidavits from them.

Photographs of church events (I say this because many homeschoolers attend church) of the family. DS-71 from a long-time pastor wouldn't hurt either.

Child medical records show the parents' names. The pediatrician may also have either a photo or a thumbprint or both on file.

Comment: DS-71 is for submitting the passport -- it's already been submitted and the Department of State still has her birth certificate. While she doesn't attend church, medical records could be possible -- but photos along with medical records/thumbprints is highly unlikely. I'm afraid this suggestion isn't suitable at this point.

Comment: DS-11 is the passport application. DS-71 is an affidavit of an identifying witness. DoS is asking for more data, and given that your friend seems to have a most unusually light footprint in the world, this is the sort of back-up she will need. https://papersplease.org/wp/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/ds-71-2-2012.pdf

Comment: DS-71 can only be used in conjunction with DS-11, which means only at the time of submitting a passport. Since she already applied for a passport six weeks ago, and the letter just arrived recently it's not possible for her to re-apply at this time since the Department of State is waiting up to 3 months for her to provide this info (which she can't) before they return her birth certificate and reject giving her a passport. What is needed is some way to rectify the issue with providing 5 year old documents that she doesn't have and that do not exist -- and there hardly seems to be options.

Comment: @Senejerry You seem pretty invested in rejecting as many suggestions people are giving you as possible. I have no idea if you have to wait for a formal rejection letter and do a complete new application, or whether they are keeping the current application open and pending, and you can add new material (e.g., DS-71) to it. Incidentally, your friend may want to contact her Congressman as they sometimes like to help constituents with this sort of problem.

Comment: I'm only going by what the documents state. The DS-71 states that it is to be used in conjunction with DS-11. If she submitted her passport then it would not be possible to use DS-71 for any further identifying purposes.

Comment: In conjunction with need not mean "executed at the same time as". If you have a pending DS-11, they may or may not accept additional documents to try to resolve the issue. If they do, I would certainly attempt to add DS-71 affidavits, in addition to the various items (e.g., medical records) already  mentioned. Thinking further, orthodontists take pictures of patients.

Comment: Well, that may be true. In any case, what good would medical records be when the document states they must be signed by her five years ago? She's never signed anything -- underage people especially aren't going to be signing medical documents; parents or guardians do.

Comment: As I said, you are wasting everyone's time by rejecting every suggestion you are given. They will also accept dated photographs as additional evidence. I'm trying to think of places your friend might have been photographed. Medical records signed by a parent are useful if the parent can also swear to the child's identity. This is probably why the younger friend got a passport with no trouble: he still needed parental signatures and *their* ID was sufficient. **What exactly have you come to this forum for? For fresh ideas on getting the passport, or merely to vent?**

Comment: It seems likely that they've rejected the birth certificate because the birth was somewhat "irregular" and they've apparently had cases where people have fraudulently certified births as having occurred in the US when they didn't. Read the comments to the question; one of my comments has three links; follow them. It seems the problem is *not* connecting the person to the birth certificate, it is the credibility of the birth certificate itself. Thus all of these well intentioned suggestions are somewhat misplaced. I agree though that @Senejerry should try DS-71; it can't hurt and might help.

Comment: @phoog Met a guy at a party who said his birth certificate gave place of birth as "Mile marker 10 of the 210" (a Los Angeles area freeway). You can guess the rest. The issue might be with an out-of-hospital birth, although if the b.c. were filed very shortly thereafter, I don't see a problem. And my pediatrician's office, for slightly older children, has computerized vaccination records and paper visit records that could be used to establish presence in the USA very shortly after birth. Unless, of course, the BC *is* fake and that explains this girl's near-invisibility in paperwork.